# My side row of the list isn't working correctly

Tags: html

So I am trying to make a menu for a boba drink shop but when listing out the milk tea the list won't show on the right. Another was that when I tried adding another picture, it would overlap with the previous one.

```css
.row {
  clear: both
}

.column {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h2><u>Yakult Tea</u></h2>
    <u1>
      <li>Mango</li>
      <li>Peach</li>
      <li>Kiwi</li>
      <li>Passionfruit</li>
      <li>Grapefruit</li>
      <li>Strawberry</li>
      <li>Green Apple</li>
      <li>Red Apple</li>
      <li>Lychee</li>
      <li>Winter Melon</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </u1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2><u>Yogumuji Yogurt</u></h2>
    <u1>
      <li>Strawberry Yogurt</li>
      <li>Fresh Yogurt</li>
      <li>Passionfruit Yogurt</li>
      <li>Purple Rice Yogurt</li>
      <li>Mango Yogurt</li>
      <li>Peach Yogurt</li>
      <li>Kiwi Yogurt</li>
      <li>Mulberry Yogurt</li>
      <li>Lychee Yogurt</li>
      <li>Pineapple Yogurt</li>
      <li>Lemon Yogurt</li>
      <li>Orange Yogurt</li>
      <li>Cherry Yogurt</li>
    </u1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2><u>Slush</u></h2>
    <u1>
      <li>Bamboo Charcoal</li>
      <li>Chocolate</li>
      <li>Honeydew</li>
      <li>Taro</li>
      <li>Peach</li>
      <li>Pineapple</li>
      <li>Plum Icy</li>
      <li>Oreo</li>
      <li>Passionfruit</li>
      <li>Lychee</li>
      <li>Matcha</li>
      <li>Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Strawberry(Milk)</li>
    </u1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <br/>
    <li>Mango(Milk)</li>
    <li>Grapefruit</li>
    <li>Kiwi</li>
    <li>Green Apple</li>
    <li>Red Apple</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
    <li>Kumquat lemon</li>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
This is where the picture would overlap with the previous one.
<img src="https://popmenucloud.com/lptemfjr/973db751-7915-4c33-abcf-784ef635b66e.jpg" width="285" height="350">

<body>
  <div class="row2">
    <div class="column">
      <style>
        .row2 {
          clear: both
        }
        
        .column {
          width: 20%;
          float: left;
        }
      </style>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <h2><u>Macchiato Slush</u></h2>
    <u1>
      <li>Strawberry</li>
      <li>Mango</li>
      <li>Peach</li>
      <li>Mulberry</li>
      <li>PassionFruit</li>
      <li>Lemon</li>
      <li>Plum</li>
    </u1>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <br/>
    <h2><u>Milk Tea</u></h2>
    <u1>
      <li>Sigature Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Green Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Honey Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Mint Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Caramel Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Coconut Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Almond Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Oolong Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Bamboo Charcoal Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Tiramisu Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Taro Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Matcha Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Barley Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Strawberry Milk Tea</li>
      <li>Winter Melon Milk Tea</li>
    </u1>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: did add the row and column thing at the top?

Comment: I also tried to change the column  space but it won't change.

Answer (score 0):

```css
Try this:

.column {
position: relative;
left: how many px it requires to go to the right;
}
```